# Appending class instance to another class's list variable via methods

Tags: python, list, class, object, append

I want to create a `Band` class and a `Musician` class. I'm trying to add a `Musician` to a `Band`. I am using Python 2.7.6.

```
class Band(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
    def hire_musician(self,member):
        self.members.append(member)
        print self.members


class Musician(object):
    def __init__(self, sounds,isDrummer):
        self.sounds = sounds
        self.isDrummer = isDrummer

    def solo(self, length):
        for i in range(length):
            print self.sounds[i % len(self.sounds)],
        print ""

class Drummer(Musician):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Drummer, self).__init__(["Hi", "Hat"],True)


Jingle = Band()
ruben = Drummer()

Jingle.hire_musician(ruben)
```

Error I get is

```
[<__main__.Drummer object at 0x7fb4785cba10>]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you're doing *anything* wrong? You have a list with a drummer in it; what were you expecting?!

Comment: I want the hire_musician to print the list of musicians for that band. But, the result I get is not what I wanted.

Comment: That's *exactly* what it's doing... Again, what result *were* you expecting?

Comment: Ah. How do I display human readable members list? like ruben, nigel and so on.

Comment: You need to implement `__str__` (string) and/or `__repr__` (representation) to tell Python how you want the instance to be displayed. But note that the name Ruben isn't currently stored anywhere within the instance...

Comment: As your objects become more complex, it's unlikely they will know how to present themselves in an appropriate way.

Comment: the methods indicated by @jonrsharpe go in the `Musician` class (and/or sublcasses). Then the `hire_musician` method in the `Band` class can simply loop the list and print its elements `for m in self.members: print m`

Comment: BTW, why is `Drummer`'s constructor calling its base class'? If it's not doing anyhting else, you can just remove it since it will be called by default. And instantiate a drummer like `ruben = Drummer(["Hi", "Hat"],True)`

Comment: I have guitarist, bassist and multiple other classes inhering the musician class. The band class will play tunes starting with the drummer followed by bassist.

Comment: The order of the members is unrelated to how you create the objects (i.e. what parameters you provide to them)

Comment: Makes sense. I can pass the sounds while creating the object. Thanks Pynchia and Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution by only adding a name attribute

```
class Band(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
    def hire_musician(self,member):
        self.members.append(member)
        for member in self.members:
            print(member.name)

class Musician(object):
    def __init__(self, name, sounds,isDrummer):
        self.sounds = sounds
        self.isDrummer = isDrummer
        self.name = name

    def solo(self, length):
        for i in range(length):
            print(self.sounds[i % len(self.sounds)],)
            print('')

class Drummer(Musician):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Drummer, self).__init__(name, ["Hi", "Hat"],True)

Jingle = Band()
ruben = Drummer('ruben')
Jingle.hire_musician(ruben)
```